# Screen mirroring to TV on Debian

Tags: debian, display

I'm trying to mirror the display of my screen to a wireless TV that's on the same Network via WiFi. So the situation is that I have an ASUS screen that's connected to my LAPTOP via HDMI. Since my box doesn't have any other way to connect the second screen via HDMI I am trying to use the Samsung SmartTV's Screen Mirroring functions. I am dual booting windows and when I right click any video file and Cast to Device, it detects the screen and the whole Desktop is casted. It has latency but I'm perfectly fine with it since I use it for image views only. I want this same function on Debian. I'm using XFCE Debian 10. I have tried Chromecast but the chromium detects the screen on cast menu but does not Support the device, I have tried VLC' Render devices and that gets stuck on Scanning... (Maybe I'm missing something on that one). I can not use Gnome as it's havier than XFCE and my work needs the lightest Desktop Environment. Please if there is absolutely any way I can use the second screen please help.

Info summary :

Intel i7 X 4 CPUs

GTX 1050

1 HDMI, 3 USB ports

Debian 10 XFCE

The TV is Samsung Smart TV

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

[gnome-network-displays](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-network-displays) is principally working for me, the performance could be better though (it lags pretty much, Debian 12, Cinnamon desktop). It is marked as *experimental* by the developers and is actively being worked on, so one can hope that it will improved.

It is shipped with Debian, even with the current version (as of the date of this post) and can be installed via `sudo apt install gnome-network-displays`.

It works for my FireTV-stick (when I disable my ufw) and Samsung devices are listed as `working`, so you could give it a try.